# Visual Studio 2017 remote docker compose failed with volume mounting errors

Tags: visual-studio, docker, docker-compose

I am using VS2017 15.8.1 with a local Docker configured to talk to a remote Docker server on a Server 2016. "docker version" works from the remote client.

```
C:\>docker version
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ee-16
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.7
 Git commit:   9ef4f0a
 Built:        Thu Jul 26 16:43:19 2018
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.06.2-ee-16
  API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:   go1.8.7
  Git commit:   9ef4f0a
  Built:        Thu Jul 26 16:52:17 2018
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

I created a new AspNet Core 2.1 project with Docker support. Docker compose failed with mounting errors for the following volumes which is expected since my user profile is not present on the Docker server:

volumes:
    - C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro
    - C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
    - C:\Users\user1\onecoremsvsmon\15.0.28010.0:C:\remote_debugger:ro

Is remote Docker server supported by VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, using a remote machine as the docker host is currently not supported. More info here: https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/151.

Comment: I figured this is not supported. It will be nice if remote docker host is supported by Studio though.